# Formula field giving a value 25

Tags: formula, fields

I am trying to set up a field [FormulaVideo] that will give a value 25 only if [Has_Video_Type__c] != None. Has video is a picklist field.

This is where i am at.

```
 IF( ISPICKVAL( Has_Video_Type__c , "No") , 25, 0)
```

Comment: You've mentioned a value `none` in the original question and `no` in the comment, which one is correct? Also, is no/none an actual value of the picklist or is it the default `-- None --` value you're trying to check against?

Comment: Hi @Bachovski i want to check the default value --None-- if possible.

Comment: Try empty string '' instead. - - None - - is just the display value, the actual value is an empty string

Comment: Actually for this field no is good, sorry i mixed it with another field.
I am almost there. Changed it with CASE() instead of IF()
CASE( Has_Video_Type__c, "Live", "25","0", "VoD","25","0", "No","0","0")

Now the only problem that i have is when i test it. For value of VoD it gives 0 instead of 25, going between values. Live works fine so as No.

Thanks,
Darko

Answer (score 2):

Solution to my question.

CASE( Has_Video_Type__c, "Live", "25", "VoD","25", "No","0","null")

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `CASE` function properly, you're not following the order of the parameters correctly in your comment:

`CASE(expression, value1, result1, value2, result2,...,else_result)`

Try this:

`CASE(Has_Video_Type__c, "Live", "25", "VoD", "25", "0")`

Means if the value is "Live", evaluate 25. If it's "VoD" again "25" and everything else, "0". Or if you want to specifically include "No" and associate it with "0" value, but have different default value, this will be your solution:

`CASE(Has_Video_Type__c, "Live", "25", "VoD", "25", "No", "0", "DEFAULTHERE")`